# cannot find symbol return RxRoom.createSingle when a dao is set to return Single<List<DummyObject>>

Tags: android, rx-java, android-room, rx-android

i'm actually new to rxjava and was trying to use it with room by returng Single> from my dao  but i keep getting  cannot find symbol return RxRoom.createSingle at build time,  below is my dao

```
@Transaction
@Query("SELECT * FROM child_dependent_table WHERE isPrincipalActive =1")
Single<List<ChildAndBiometric>> childListByActive();
```

incase you need any information

Comment: try these dependencies `implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:2.2.3"`
    `implementation "androidx.room:room-rxjava2:2.2.3"`
    `annotationProcessor  "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.2.3"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:2.2.5"
kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.2.5"
implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:2.2.5"
implementation "androidx.room:room-rxjava2:2.2.5"
```

hey are you sure you have the dependencies as outlined above? I had an issue in my project where I was using the `arch-components` import instead of the android-x version. if you look at the source for that version it only has the statics to create Flowable and Observable, which will give you the error you are seeing

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the following dependency to your grade setup:

`implementation "androidx.room:room-rxjava2:$room_version"`

Comment: I have the dependency already and i can Maybe<E> with it but single dont seem to work